# Convex hull of the Mandelbrot set

Tags: fractals, complex-dynamics

What is the [convex hull](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexHull.html) of the Mandelbrot set?

I know that the leftmost point is $c=-2$ and I *thought* the extreme vertical points were $c=\pm i$. Sheldon's answers says they're not.

I think that the line segments defined by $-2$ and the extreme vertical points are edges of the convex hull, but the edges on the right are harder. In particular, I don't know the extreme horizontal points on the right.

I wonder whether the convex hull of the Mandelbrot set is a convex polygon, that is, has a *finite* number of vertices.

$\hskip5cm$[image]

Comment: I don't think this is known, neither the convex hull nor even the points with largest real part, i.e., the rightmost points.

Comment: @LukasGeyer, do you know a reference where this is discussed?

Answer (score 4):

There is a previous mathstack question on the largest imaginary point of the Mandelbrot set, which is $z \approx -0.207107867093967+1.122757063632597i$

[Supremum of all y-coordinates of the Mandelbrot set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936462/supremum-of-all-y-coordinates-of-the-mandelbrot-set)

Also see mrob's website, for both the northernmost point and the easternmost point
http://mrob.com/pub/muency/northernmostpoint.html
http://mrob.com/pub/muency/easternmostpoint.html

There are several other pertinent convex hull points on the right of the Mandelbrot set, but I wouldn't know how to generate them.

Comment: Oh, so $\pm i$ are not extreme points!

Comment: yeah, I added the approximate coordinates of the imaginary extreme in the answer.

Comment: @lhf, given the self-similar fractal nature of these Mandelbrot extremum points, I wonder if there might be an infinite number of points of contact with the convex hull...